# Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Boolean]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

I am trying to protect one of my routes in this Angular app I have made. I think I have implemented it correctly however, am running into this error when the negative scenario is invoked: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Boolean]`. What I also can't understand is that it seems to work when I meet the conditions to allow the route?! Code below:

**Routing Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


import { RecipesComponent } from './recipes/recipes.component';
import { ShoppingListComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.component';
import { RecipeDetailComponent } from './recipes/recipe-detail/recipe-detail.component';
import { RecipeStartComponent } from './recipes/recipe-start/recipe-start.component';
import { RecipeEditComponent } from './recipes/recipe-edit/recipe-edit.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/guard.service';




const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/recipes',pathMatch: 'full' },
    {path: 'recipes', component: RecipesComponent, 
              children:[
        {path: '', component: RecipeStartComponent},
        {path: 'new', component:RecipeEditComponent},
        {path: ':id', component: RecipeDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
        {path: ':id/edit', component:RecipeEditComponent}
    ]},
    {path: 'shopping-list', component: ShoppingListComponent}
]





@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

**Auth Service**

```
import { OnDestroy, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { RecipeService } from "../recipes/recipe.service";

@Injectable()

export class AuthService implements OnDestroy  {




constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService){
  console.log(this.loadedReceipe)
}


private loadedReceipe: boolean = false

setRecipe(){
this.loadedReceipe = true;
console.log(`setting the recipe to true`)
}



isAuthenticated() {
  const promise = new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      if(this.recipeService.getRecipes().length > 0){
        console.log(`resolving`)
        resolve (true)
      }else{  
        console.log(`rejecting`)
        reject(false)
      }
    }
  );
  return promise;
}




ngOnDestroy()
{
  console.log(this.loadedReceipe);
}

}
```

**Guard Service**

```
import {
    CanActivate,
    CanActivateChild,
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    RouterStateSnapshot,
    Router
  } from '@angular/router';

  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs'


  import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'  
})


  export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}


    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean{
                      return this.authService.isAuthenticated() 
                    .then(
                  (authenticated: boolean) => {
                      if (authenticated) {
                         console.log(`got here1`)
                            return true;
                        } else {
                          console.log(`got here2`)
                            this.router.navigate(['/recipes']);

              }
      }
    )

  }

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
return this.canActivate(route, state);
}




  }
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would expect the issue to be in the else in the gothere2 case. It is not authenticating and is promised to return a Boolean. However you are not returning anything. Where in the authentication case you are. How I would fix:

```
              (authenticated: boolean) => {
                  if (authenticated) {
                     console.log(`got here1`)
                        return true;
                    } else {
                      console.log(`got here2`)
                        this.router.navigate(['/recipes']);
                            return false;

          }
```

Comment: https://juristr.com/blog/2018/11/better-route-guard-redirects/ ... the correct way of redirect in guard

Comment: Hey, I've implemented the ```return false ``` and its still throwing the ```ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Boolean]``` in my application, any ideas? I'll give that post a read, cheers for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it out from my end was getting the same error and this is how i fixed it.
[image]

As you can see in the screen shot I am not allowing the user to access the server route.
My Initial Auth service with isAuthenticated() method is as following
[image]

In order to prevent this error we need to catch it as shown below.
[image]

Now i am not getting any error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Faced the exact same error but for a different scenario than the OP's.

I was rejecting a promise for an await statement and looked like error couldn't find a place to get caught after rejection and threw "Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Boolean]".

Placing my await statement under try catch block fixed the error.

Adding my code below in case someone encounters same issue:

**DataService.ts**

```
serviceCall(): Promise<SomeEntity | HttpErrorResponse> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        myService.doSomeWork()
        .then(data => {
            resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            reject(error)
        })
    })
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
try {
    await DataService.serviceCall();
} catch (error) {
    // error from the rejected promise should get caught here
    console.log(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime you get error due to catch try to open it in incognito mode

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using the version >=7. Try to replace

```
this.router.navigate(['/recipes']);
```

with

```
return this.router.parseUrl('/recipes');
```

You may also get rid of

```
: Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean
```

as typescript will be able to infer it.

Comment: Removing types defeats the purpose of using typescript. Also, there is nothing wrong with `this.router.navigate(['url'])`

Comment: @mwilson that is not true in this case... typescript will infer the return type automatically... you do not have to explicitly declare the return type